# C++ syntax for interaction between classes and struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm working on an assignment in my first semester of C++ and I just can't figure out working syntax for it. I need to pass a struct as a parameter to a class function using a pointer. This code I've copied is my best attempt, and it will compile but it crashes when it asks for the first name. When I try variations in the syntax, I get errors about incomplete struct, undefined variables (warrior was  or invalid operators. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class StarWars
{
    public:
        int totalNumber;
        struct data_clone
        {
            int ID, timeCounter;
            string name;
        };
        data_clone *warrior;
        void createClone()
        {
            cout << "How many clone warriors do you want to create in total?" << endl;
            cin >> totalNumber;
        }
        void input(struct data_clone *pointer, int total)
        {

            for(int i = 1; i <= total; i++)
            {
                cout << "For warrior number " << i << ":" << endl;
                cout << "What is the warrior's name?" << endl;
                cin >> pointer[i].name;
                cout << "What is the warrior's ID number?" << endl;
                cin >> pointer[i].ID;
                cout << "What is the warrior's time counter?" << endl;
                cin >> pointer[i].timeCounter;
            }
        }
        void lifeSpan(struct data_clone *pointer, int total)
        {
            for(int i = 1; i <= total; i++)
            {
                cout << "Warrior number " << pointer[i].name << ": " << endl;
                while(pointer[i].timeCounter > 0)
                {
                    cout << "Warrior name: " << pointer[i].name << endl;
                    cout << "Warrior ID number: " << pointer[i].ID << endl;
                    cout << "Warrior time counter: " << pointer[i].timeCounter << endl;
                    cout << "Clone is alive." << endl;
                    pointer[i].timeCounter--;
                }
                cout << "Warrior name: " << pointer[i].name << endl;
                cout << "Warrior ID number: " << pointer[i].ID << endl;
                cout << "Warrior time counter: " << pointer[i].timeCounter << endl;
                cout << "Clone is dead." << endl;
            }
        }


};

int main(void)
{
    StarWars clones;
    clones.createClone();
    clones.input(clones.warrior, clones.totalNumber);
    clones.lifeSpan(clones.warrior, clones.totalNumber);
}
```

Comment: Seems `warrior` is a dangled pointer.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are basically the same in C++, so there are no special rules for making one "interact" with the other.

Comment: You have a pointer, but you never set it to point anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialise the memory warrior points to, so you're working with uninitiailised memory - always a bad thing. There's two things to keep in mind here:

When working with pointers, always initialise the memory behind them first. Prefer using RAII concepts like std::unique_ptr / std::shared_ptr

```
void DoStuff(Widget* w);

std::unique_ptr<Widget> pw = std::make_unique<Widget>();
DoStuff(w.get());
```

When working with normal variables, use the dereference / reference operators to take a pointer to the variable.

```
void DoStuff(Widget* w);

Widget widget;
DoStuff(&w);
```

Comment: Thank you for the information--I'm reading up on these smart pointers now. I don't think the professor intended us to use them for this particular assignment, but I'm always happy to learn better ways to do things!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct data_clone
{
    int ID, timeCounter;
    string name;
};

class StarWars
{
private:
       data_clone *warrior;
       int totalNumber;
    public:
        StarWars()
        {

        }
        ~StarWars()
        {
            delete[] warrior; // clean up 
        }

        void createClone();
        void input();
        void lifeSpan();
  };

void StarWars::createClone()
{
    cout << "How many clone warriors do you want to create in total?" << endl;
    cin >> totalNumber;
    // construct structure baased on input
    warrior = new data_clone[totalNumber];
}

 void StarWars::input()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++)
    {
        cout << "For warrior number " << i+1 << ":" << endl;
        cout << "What is the warrior's name?" << endl;
        cin >> warrior[i].name;
        cout << "What is the warrior's ID number?" << endl;
        cin >> warrior[i].ID;
        cout << "What is the warrior's time counter?" << endl;
        cin >> warrior[i].timeCounter;
    }
}

void StarWars::lifeSpan()
{
    std::cout<<"**********Print data**********\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++)
    {
        cout << "Warrior number " << warrior[i].name << ": " << endl;
        while(warrior[i].timeCounter > 0)
        {
            cout << "Warrior name: " << warrior[i].name << endl;
            cout << "Warrior ID number: " << warrior[i].ID << endl;
            cout << "Warrior time counter: " << warrior[i].timeCounter << endl;
            cout << "Clone is alive." << endl;
            warrior[i].timeCounter--;
        }
        cout << "Warrior name: " << warrior[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Warrior ID number: " << warrior[i].ID << endl;
        cout << "Warrior time counter: " << warrior[i].timeCounter << endl;
        cout << "Clone is dead." << endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    StarWars clones;
    clones.createClone();
    clones.input();
    clones.lifeSpan();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never created your clones, you only read how many there should be.
Allocate space for them:

```
void createClone()
{
    cout << "How many clone warriors do you want to create in total?" << endl;
    cin >> totalNumber;
    warrior = new data_clone[totalNumber];
}
```

Your array indexes are also off - an array of size `N` is indexed from `0` to `N - 1`.

But the more common way of handling this is to pass the amount to the constructor and let the object handle its own members:

```
class StarWars
{
public:
    StarWars(int clones)
        : totalNumber(clones),
          warrior(new data_clone[clones])
    {

    }

    void input()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++)
        {
            cout << "For warrior number " << i << ":" << endl;
            cout << "What is the warrior's name?" << endl;
            cin >> warrior[i].name;
            cout << "What is the warrior's ID number?" << endl;
            cin >> warrior[i].ID;
            cout << "What is the warrior's time counter?" << endl;
            cin >> warrior[i].timeCounter;
        }
    }

    void lifeSpan()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++)
        {
            cout << "Warrior number " << i << ": " << endl;
            while(warrior[i].timeCounter > 0)
            {
                cout << "Warrior name: " << warrior[i].name << endl;
                cout << "Warrior ID number: " << warrior[i].ID << endl;
                cout << "Warrior time counter: " << warrior[i].timeCounter << endl;
                cout << "Clone is alive." << endl;
                warrior[i].timeCounter--;
            }
            cout << "Warrior name: " << warrior[i].name << endl;
            cout << "Warrior ID number: " << warrior[i].ID << endl;
            cout << "Warrior time counter: " << warrior[i].timeCounter << endl;
            cout << "Clone is dead." << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int totalNumber;
    struct data_clone
    {
        int ID, timeCounter;
        string name;
    };
    data_clone *warrior;
};

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    cout << "How many clone warriors do you want to create in total?" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    StarWars clones(number);
    clones.input();
    clones.lifeSpan();
}
```

Note that you need to handle the destructor, the copy constructor, and the assignment operator properly as well (left as an exercise).

Comment: Thank you so much, your top solution solved the immediate problem (how the professor seems to have intended me to do it). And I'm experimenting now with the constructor and such, as you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

class StarWars
{
private:
      struct data_clone
        {
            int ID, timeCounter;
            string name;
        };

```
public:
    StarWars()
    {
        warrior = new data_clone[4];
    }
    ~StarWars()
    {
        delete[] warrior;
    }
    int totalNumber;

    data_clone *warrior;
    void createClone()
    {
        cout << "How many clone warriors do you want to create in total?" << endl;
        cin >> totalNumber;
    }
    void input(struct data_clone *pointer, int total)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            cout << "For warrior number " << i << ":" << endl;
            cout << "What is the warrior's name?" << endl;
            cin >> pointer[i].name;
            cout << "What is the warrior's ID number?" << endl;
            cin >> pointer[i].ID;
            cout << "What is the warrior's time counter?" << endl;
            cin >> pointer[i].timeCounter;
        }
    }
    void lifeSpan(struct data_clone *pointer, int total)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            cout << "Warrior number " << pointer[i].name << ": " << endl;
            while(pointer[i].timeCounter > 0)
            {
                cout << "Warrior name: " << pointer[i].name << endl;
                cout << "Warrior ID number: " << pointer[i].ID << endl;
                cout << "Warrior time counter: " << pointer[i].timeCounter << endl;
                cout << "Clone is alive." << endl;
                pointer[i].timeCounter--;
            }
            cout << "Warrior name: " << pointer[i].name << endl;
            cout << "Warrior ID number: " << pointer[i].ID << endl;
            cout << "Warrior time counter: " << pointer[i].timeCounter << endl;
            cout << "Clone is dead." << endl;
        }
    }
```

};

Note: I just hardcoded it which is not the correct way, it force you to enter only 4 tyeps of dataclone 
"warrior = new data_clone[4];"

you will at least get your result

Comment: Considering this is the OP's first assignment with C++, they're most likely unfamiliar with new / delete and the advantages / disadvantages of allocated memory in C++, your answer should elaborate on this better instead of giving them more stuff to copy.